# Creating Views Joining Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create views of a database containing information about horses, more specifically horses, their owners, and the horse boarder. The view must join three tables. I have to create a view of "first name, last name, primary phone, and barnname". Then I have to join tables "boarder, horse, and boarder_horse" to create the relationship. I can't figure out how to connect the various tables together.

So far, this is what I have:

```
CREATE VIEW horse_owner
AS
SELECT b.boarder firstname, b.boarder lastname, b.boarder primaryphone, 
h.horse barname

FROM boarder b
INNER JOIN horse h
ON bh.horse_id = h.id
INNER JOIN boarder_horse
ON bh.boarder_id = b.id

ORDER BY LastName DESC;
```

I don't understand how to correctly link the appropriate tables together.

Comment: your alias for boarder  is `b`, but you try to join it with `bh`

Comment: `INNER JOIN horse h ON b.horse_id = h.id` and you have no alias for `boarder_horse`

Comment: @WillardSolutions so I need to join it to horse instead?

Comment: Can you give sample data for the three tables, and expected output for that sample?

Comment: I tried posting pictures of the tables im referencing but they wont save

Comment: I got the pictures to post, those are the tables I'm trying to join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had order of `JOIN`s wrong. Also, you were missing alias `bh`. Try:

```
CREATE VIEW horse_owner
AS
SELECT b.firstname, b.lastname, b.primaryphone, 
h.barname

FROM boarder b
INNER JOIN boarder_horse bh
ON bh.boarder_id = b.id
INNER JOIN horse h
ON bh.horse_id = h.id

ORDER BY LastName DESC;
```